# How to convert an unsigned long long to QString

Tags: qt

I am trying to convert an unsigned long long to QString by using QString::number(). But it's giving me the following error "call of overloaded 'number(long long unsigned int*&)' is ambiguous. Can anyone help me?

**EDIT**

```
GetBoardSN(0, SN);
ui->tableWidget_Ethernet->setItem(0,2,new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(SN)));
```

Header file :
`int GetBoardSN(int instance, unsigned long long *SN);`

Comment: What is `SN`? GetBoardSN expects a pointer, but when you call it, you don't take the address. So is `SN` a pointer or a number? The error message also looks like you are passing a pointer, where QString::number() expects a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SN` seems to be a pointer (`unsigned long long *`). Otherwise you would not be able to call `GetBoardSN` that way. So your code assumes the variable to have two different types. `GetBoardSN` requires SN to be a `unsigned long long*` pointer, `String::number()` requires SN to be a value for example of type `unsigned long long`.

To solve this, depending on your context, you can either declare SN as a non-pointer type and call GetBoardSn with a reference to this instance:

```
GetBoardSN(0, &SN);
ui->tableWidget_Ethernet->setItem(0,2,new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(SN)));
```

or keep the pointer type and resolve the pointer before accessing its value:

```
GetBoardSN(0, SN);
ui->tableWidget_Ethernet->setItem(0,2,new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(*SN)));
```

Which one is the better solution depends on your overall usage of SN.